# Getting Table and Column Names from DbContext

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-6.1

With the new Public Mapping API what is the proper way of going from an Entity to getting the corresponding database schema and table names, and the mapping of the entities properties to column names?

Answer (score 0):

Here is a reference with a ADO.NET Entity Data Model generated with Database First approach. It uses the schema provided by the connection of DbContext.

Schema Restriction is not enforced but just returns more clear results. For further information, please take a look with 
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc716722(v=vs.110).aspx

```
  using (var dbContext = new DbGeneratedByEfEntities())
  {
    var conn = dbContext.Database.Connection;
    conn.Open();

    var restrictions = default(string[]);

    // please replace DbName and Owner with the actual value
    restrictions = new string[] { "DbName", "dbo" };

    // get DataTable from schema with collection name of "Tables"
    var tablesDataTable = conn.GetSchema(SqlClientMetaDataCollectionNames.Tables, restrictions);

    // show column names
    Debug.WriteLine(string.Join(" | ", tablesDataTable.Columns.Cast<DataColumn>()));

    // show row contents, table names from schema
    tablesDataTable.Rows.Cast<DataRow>().ToList().ForEach(r =>
    {
      Debug.WriteLine(string.Join(" | ", r.ItemArray));
    });

    /************************/

    // please replace DbName, Owner and TableName with the actual value
    restrictions = new string[] { "DbName", "dbo", "TableName" };

    // get DataTable from schema with collection name of "Columns"
    var colsDataTable = conn.GetSchema(SqlClientMetaDataCollectionNames.Columns, restrictions);

    // show column names
    Debug.WriteLine(string.Join(" | ", colsDataTable.Columns.Cast<DataColumn>()));

    // show row contents, field names from schema
    colsDataTable.Rows.Cast<DataRow>().ToList().ForEach(r =>
    {
      Debug.WriteLine(string.Join(" | ", r.ItemArray));
    });
  }
```